# How to set up location for myweb.property so that AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getEnvironment can find it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to java web app development and I am trying to setup my webapp with spring mvc. My code snippet is like this

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.getEnvironment();
    context.register(SiteSpringMVCConfig.class);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the location of your property file in web.xml file and get it from the instance of applicationContext.Below code snippets will help you.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name> contextClass </param-name>
   <param-value>
   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
  </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <context-param>
   <param-name> contextConfigLocation </param-name>
   <param-value>classpath: //your file location in classpath </param-value>
 </context-param>
 <listener>
   <listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Other way is , you need to get the file loaded to your application instance.

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
context.setConfigLocation("classpath:<your file location>");
```

Comment: I tried the second way but it didn't work. It looks like it should but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding

```
@PropertySource("classpath:myweb.properties")
```

in `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` implementation. My properties file is in Resources folder.